# Django aggregating records for each foreign key

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm

```
class Order(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    placed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    shipped = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    delivered = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
```

I want to calculate statistics on how fast the order has been processed for each category
where process time is `delivered - shipped`

In result I want to achieve something like this:

```
[
    {
        "category": <category 1>
        "processed_time": <average processed time in seconds>
    },
    {
        "category": <category 2>
        "processed_time": <average processed time in seconds>
    },
    {
        "category": <category 3>
        "processed_time": <average processed time in seconds>
    },
]
```

I can calculate this outside of the ORM but I'd like to achieve this somehow with annotation/aggregation

```
delivered = delivered_qs.annotate(first_processed=Min("delivered"), last_processed=Max("delivered")) \
    .aggregate(processed_time=F("last_processed")-F("first_processed"))
```

This QS returns time only for all categories and I dont know how to retrieve time for each individual category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to do a `group by`, which in Django works kinda weird. For more information see [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#joins-and-aggregates)

But by first using .values you say again the queryset you gonna group by on the category. Than you determine the min, the max and the difference.

```
delivered = (
    delivered_qs
        .values('category')
        .annotate(
            first_processed=Min("delivered"), 
            last_processed=Max("delivered"),
            processed_time=F("last_processed") - F("first_processed"),
        ) 
)
```

Which, in my expectation, would return:

```
[{
    "category": 1,
    "first_processed": timedelta(), 
    "last_processed": timedelta(), 
    "processed_time": timedelta()
}, ...]
```